# How to Store Accelerometer Data for Classification by using Machine Learning

Tags: android, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I am developing an Android application that uses raw accelerometer data and I want to classify the data by using machine learning, i.e. Azure ML service. For example when device moves like a 1 in space, it should generate number 1 in text field specified in application. I decided to use Machine Learning to classify movements but I couldn't decide how to store data and send it to the machine learning service for training. For now, I am creating an SQLite table in application and add the X,Y,Z value of sensor each time sensor data gets changed. After that I am sending data to machine learning service but I have problem. The data only includes one movement for 1. How can I store multiple data for same movement and data for other movements -that will represent different numbers like 2, 3- and send them to the machine learning service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MuhammedKadirYücel, Based on my understanding, I think you want to send raw accelerometer data to Azure and store into some storage service for importing on Machine Learning service.

Per my experience, I think the best practice is that create a [EventHub](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/event-hubs/) or [IoTHub](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/iot-hub/) instance for receiving these raw accelerometer data.

Then create a [Stream Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-get-started-with-azure-stream-analytics-to-process-data-from-iot-devices/) to transfer sensor data from EventHub or IoTHub to Azure Blob Storage.

Finally, you can import these data of the blob storage on Machine Learning service, please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-import-data-from-online-sources/.